# How to use LIKE operator in Slick?

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

I am trying to use [**Slick**](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.3/introduction.html) framework for integration with **MySQL**. However whenever I use **LIKE** operator it fails with the error, as shown below.

**Code**

```
.filterIf(etilizeRequest.q.nonEmpty) {
    case ((((((prod, manRep), catRep), cnRep), pdRep), prodSkusRep), saRep) =>
        cnRep.map(_.name).like("%"+etilizeRequest.q.get+"%").get
}
```

**Error**

> slick.SlickException: Caught exception while computing default value
> for Rep[Option[_]].getOrElse -- This cannot be done lazily when the
> value is needed on the database side  at
> slick.compiler.HoistClientOps$$anonfun$rewriteDBSide$1.applyOrElse(HoistClientOps.scala:159)
> at
> slick.compiler.HoistClientOps$$anonfun$rewriteDBSide$1.applyOrElse(HoistClientOps.scala:152)
> at slick.ast.NodeOps$.r$1(Util.scala:47)    at
> slick.ast.NodeOps$.$anonfun$replace$2(Util.scala:48)  at
> slick.ast.BinaryNode.mapChildren(Node.scala:204)  at
> slick.ast.BinaryNode.mapChildren$(Node.scala:200)     at
> slick.ast.Filter.mapChildren(Node.scala:310)  at
> slick.ast.NodeOps$.g$1(Util.scala:48)     at
> slick.ast.NodeOps$.r$1(Util.scala:47)     at
> slick.ast.NodeOps$.$anonfun$replace$2(Util.scala:48) Caused by:
> slick.SlickException: Read NULL value for column
> slick.lifted.OptionColumnExtensionMethods@594b5a63    at
> slick.lifted.OptionColumnExtensionMethods$.$anonfun$get$1(ExtensionMethods.scala:39)
> at
> slick.compiler.HoistClientOps$$anonfun$rewriteDBSide$1.applyOrElse(HoistClientOps.scala:156)
> at
> slick.compiler.HoistClientOps$$anonfun$rewriteDBSide$1.applyOrElse(HoistClientOps.scala:152)
> at slick.ast.NodeOps$.r$1(Util.scala:47)    at
> slick.ast.NodeOps$.$anonfun$replace$2(Util.scala:48)  at
> slick.ast.BinaryNode.mapChildren(Node.scala:204)  at
> slick.ast.BinaryNode.mapChildren$(Node.scala:200)     at
> slick.ast.Filter.mapChildren(Node.scala:310)  at
> slick.ast.NodeOps$.g$1(Util.scala:48)     at
> slick.ast.NodeOps$.r$1(Util.scala:47)

Can someonw suggest the reasoning behind this error and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Slick can't always call `.get` on an `Option` when the `.get` happens at the SQL level. It's not clear to me when this happens, but in your example I'd guess it will be the final `.get` at the end. I think that because we'd be asking, at the database level, to turn an optional `like` expression into SQL. I don't think that's possible.

In your case there's a work around to convert an optional column to a string column:

```scala
cnRep.map(_.name).asColumnOf[String].like(...etc...)
```

...and you can omit the final `.get` call. (I actually thought automatic support for this was added in Slick 3.3, but I guess not).

You may also be able to use `filterOpt` rather than `filterIf`. That would remove one more `get` from inside your `LIKE` expression. [Section 2.9 of *Essential Slick*](https://books.underscore.io/essential-slick/essential-slick-3.html#conditional-filtering) gives some examples.